# How to highlight keywords in a ListGrid in smartGWT

Tags: highlight, smartgwt

I have ListGrid in smartGWT populated with fields and information. Some of the columns have sentences. I was wondering if it was possible to highlight all occurrences of a specific keyword. For example: If I had a sentences "The cat was fluffy" and "The cow jumped over the moon and I wanted to find all occurrences of "the", then my columns would show: "**The** cat was fluffy" and "**The** cow jumped over **the** moon".

I know that you can use the editHilites() method to highlight the entire cell of the column, but I want to highlight individual words within the column. Is there an easy/feasible way to do this in smartGWT?

Answer (score 0):

The text you are writing in the field is Html, so I think you can use your css...

Comment: is there a way to grab the cells that would normally be highlighted using the editHilites() method and then parse through that to find the string that you are searching for an then make that a different color? That was my original plan, but I'm not familiar with how the editHilites() method or the filtering works in smartgwt.

Comment: You mean you can't parse and change the html content why?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use setCellFormatter to create a cellFormatter to search through and find what I wanted to highlight.